# How to add JavaScript in Shopify public app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

Im developing a **Shopify public app using Ruby on Rails**. I want disaply some information in all the store front pages. The official documents only explains about the admin panel modifications. How can I access the store front? And where I should add the scripts, I mean in which controller?

Actually Im a PHP Developer. Im new to Shopify and also Ruby on Rails. Im trying to develop a shopify public app which will show product related information in all pages (front-end).  I followed [shopify's tutorial](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-ruby-and-sinatra) first, and created a hello world like app which displays products list in admin side. But I really cant find anything that make changes in the store frontend.

So please help me that how to make changes in frontend. Also I want to get the current user information and product details (if it is a product view page).

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question with my research and how long I reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use config.scripttags to load javascripts in shopify store front pages. The syntax will be as follows:

```
config.scripttags = [
  {event:'onload', src: 'https://domainname.com/path_to_script.js'},
]
```

You should add this code in the shopify_app Gem initializer file, which can be found in

> config/initializers/shopify_app.rb

Hope this will help someone..!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this from shopify which provides you admin APIs for add new page , update page , get customer, get products etc.. like that

[Shopify Admin APIs](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference)

there is section for online store which contains the pages API also you can see API for products , orders and customers.

you can also add your **js** file in online store pages with **https** endpoint statically in admin account of shopify 
example code

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script async="true" src="https://www.example.com/test.js"></script>
```

add your js code like this in online store page and check that your js is loading there or not

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're asking where you need to place your JS files to have them load up on the Front End. This should help:

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html#locations

> Whether you use the Rails asset pipeline or add a  tag directly to a view, you have to make a choice about where to put any local JavaScript file.
>
> We have a choice of three locations for a local JavaScript file:
>
> the app/assets/javascripts folder
>
> the lib/assets/javascripts folder
>
> the vendor/assets/javascripts folder
>
> Here are guidelines for selecting a location for your scripts:
>
> Use app/assets/javascripts for JavaScript you create for your application.
>
> Use lib/assets/javascripts for scripts that are shared by many applications (but use a gem if you can).
>
> Use vendor/assets/javascripts for copies of jQuery plugins, etc., from other developers.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. But it is related to rails application. What I need is Rails app using Shopify_app Gem.